# Send message to a specific user trough com.facebook.orca

Tags: android, facebook-messenger

I've tried already the follow, but seems like it does not works:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test" );
sendIntent.setType( "text/plain" );
sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, "{facebook_user_id}" );
sendIntent.setPackage( "com.facebook.orca" );

startActivity( sendIntent );
```

- How to send a message to a specific Facebook user trough Facebook's Messenger ?